# Remove directories via pattern match | using bash script / Python

Tags: python, bash, scripting

Assuming input *.txt file contains

```
//this text file usually contains unique id's
1effaj
21easd
231asd
71823aq
```

One of my main directories contains child directories like below

```
hello_1afadf
ring_1effaj
chain_asd123
```

Using the *.txt file as input, I want to remove all 1st level directories that either match or do not match the above pattern

If I want to remove all directories that match the pattern from the text file, then only "ring_1effaj" should be removed / deleted.

Or can someone suggest how can I use multiple indexes of an array if the lines of that input text are stored in multiple array's.

```
rm -rf $(ls -aI "*_${b[1]}")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: will the id be always at the end ? is the id list longer than the directory list or the other way around ?

Comment: the number of items in the list are usually lesser than the directories.

Comment: Lately it seems that the default reaction of some is to vote to close with "Needs details or clarity". I don't see anything unclear in this question, and OP has answered  the requests for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that you don't have any strange filenames:**

```
find . \! -name '.' -type d -prune | 
     grep  -v -f ids.txt | 
     xargs echo rm -rf
```

This should work with any POSIX [find](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html)/[grep](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html)/[xargs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xargs.html). Remove the `echo` when you are satisfied, remove `-v` to delete the matching directories.

- **find** - search for files

  - `\! -name '.'` - file is not named '.', so it doesn't include the root directory (you might need to adapt that if you run this from another directory)
  - `-type d` - select only directories
  - `-prune` - once found, don't enter a directory, just print it
- **grep** - filter

  - `-f ids.txt` - load patterns from file ids.txt
  - `-v` - return lines that don't match
- **xargs** - run a command with arguments from standard input

**Note:** if you run find from another directory, you will need to change `-name` to match the base directory where your directories are. Example:

```
$ find ./60476598/ \! -name '.' -type d -prune
./60476598/
$ find ./60476598/ \! -name '60476598' -type d -prune
./60476598/chain_asd123
./60476598/hello?_1effaj
$ find /home/sorin/tmp/60476598/ \! -name '60476598' -type d -prune
/home/sorin/tmp/60476598/chain_asd123
/home/sorin/tmp/60476598/hello?_1effaj
```

In this case, I have my test setup in a directory named 60476598 (the question id). If you don't take that in account, the you can see that it will return only the base directory, but if you change the `-name '.'` to `-name '60476598'` it will work as expected. You have to use just the name of the directory, not the entire path.

**A slightly better approach**, if you have a set of utilities that support null separation of records:

```
find . \! -name '.' -type d -prune -print0 | 
     grep -v -z -f ids.txt | 
     xargs --null echo rm -rf
```

In this case [`-print0`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Print-File-Name) tells `find` to output results separated by the null char, [`-z`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Other-Options) tells `grep` that lines are separated by the null char, and `--null` tells [`xargs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#xargs-options) that input lines are separated by null. These options are not required by POSIX compatibility however they are available for GNU variants of these tools.

**What is the difference ?**

Suppose you have a directory that has a new line in its name:

```
ls -1la
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  6 sorin pi 4096 Mar  1 18:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 31 sorin pi 4096 Mar  1 17:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 sorin pi 4096 Mar  1 17:26 chain_asd123
drwxr-xr-x  2 sorin pi 4096 Mar  1 17:26 hello_1afadf
drwxr-xr-x  2 sorin pi 4096 Mar  1 18:18 hello_1effaj
drwxr-xr-x  2 sorin pi 4096 Mar  1 18:17 hello?_1effaj
-rw-r--r--  1 sorin pi   29 Mar  1 17:28 ids.txt
```

In this case hello?_1effaj has a newline embedded in the name.

For the first command the output would be:

```
$ find . \! -name '.' -type d -prune | grep  -f ids.txt | xargs echo rm -rf
rm -rf _1effaj ./hello_1effaj
```

(it would try to delete a directory named `_1effaj` but `hello?_1effaj` would be untouched)

```
$ find . \! -name '.' -type d -prune -print0 | grep  -z -f ids.txt | xargs --null echo rm -rf
rm -rf ./hello
_1effaj ./hello_1effaj
```

This would successfully delete the directory `hello?_1effaj`.

**How do I check if I have such a filename ?**:

```
find -name '*
*'
```

this should work in any POSIX shell.

Or in bash you can use: `find -name \*$'\n'\*`

Comment: That's simply outstanding.

Comment: Just one question, I'm quite new to bash as well. So using xargs prior to rm - rf is equivalent of using rm - rf <directory 1....directory n> is it??